# Ifelse with multiple conditions across many rows/

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, data-wrangling

**Looking to add a column based on the values of other columns, but over more than one row.**

```
DF:
Studios: A, B, C ...
Year:2000-2020
Id:r1,r2,r3,r4...
Top1:0,1,0,0,0
```

**Starting data set looks like this :**

| id | Year | Studio | Top1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| r1 | 2020 | A | 0 |
| r2 | 2001 | B | 0 |
| r3 | 2019 | A | 1 |
| r45 | 2005 | D | 1 |
| r34 | 2005 | E | 1 |

**Ifelse Statemets (probably):**
What I am trying to achieve is "create column `PreviousTop1`.If column `Studio1=studioX` where `year=year-1` and `Top1=1`.
*For clarification: studio1 is referring to the studio1 my id is currently at. While studioX is the same studio as studio1 in different id.

**Desired Output:**

| id | Year | Studio | Top1 | PreviousTop1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| r1 | 2020 | A | 0 | 1 |
| r2 | 2001 | B | 0 | 0 |
| r3 | 2019 | A | 1 | 0 |
| r45 | 2005 | D | 1 | 0 |
| r34 | 2005 | E | 1 | 0 |

**Reasoning for proper Answer**
`PreviousTop=1`,in row 1 because r3 exists.
So I need to check the whole column for 1 instance that conditions are true and then break.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to solve your problem differently than with an ifelse:

Create a table with only the Top1 per year. Join this table with your first table just on a year=year-1 basis:

```
top1 <- table %>% filter(Top1=1) %>% mutate(Year = Year +1)
table %>% left_join(top1, by="Year")
```

Comment: I don't understand really how this helps, by ```top1```I have all id's that was top1 and just add 1 in the year.  i dont follow how this help tbh.

Comment: If you find Studio A beeing top 1 in 2019, you add 1 to receive 2020. Now in the join, the StudioA will be added to the 2020 line

Answer (score 0):

You can try this base R approach :

```
#Initialise PreviousTop1 column to 0
df$PreviousTop1 <- 0
#Find whose previous year data is present in the dataframe
inds <- which((df$Year - 1) %in% df$Year)
#Assign 1 to PreviousTop1 if Top1 = 1
df$PreviousTop1[inds] <- +(df$Top1[match(df$Year[inds] - 1, df$Year)] == 1)
df

#   id Year Studio Top1 PreviousTop1
#1  r1 2020      A    0            1
#2  r2 2001      B    0            0
#3  r3 2019      A    1            0
#4 r45 2005      D    1            0
#5 r34 2005      E    1            0
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = c("r1", "r2", "r3", "r45", "r34"), Year = c(2020L, 
2001L, 2019L, 2005L, 2005L), Studio = c("A", "B", "A", "D", "E"), 
Top1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Guys, thanks for the recommendation and sorry for ghosting but I had focused on my task at hand.
the code that worked for me is :
SQLtop10 <-sqldf(
  'select s.id, s.year, s.production,
      "1" as PreviousTop10
      from DF  s
      join
      (SELECT DISTINCT production as production, year as year
      FROM DF
      WHERE InTop10 = 1
      and production is not null) as temp
      on production = temp.production and year = temp.year + 1;
       ')

where production is studio but in my df.